# Retrieved files were corrupted after file carving

Tags: forensics

I have used [scalpel](https://github.com/sleuthkit/scalpel) to carve files from a memory dump. But some of the image files are incomplete or corrupted . I cannot see an image preview. What will be the reason for this ?

Comment: the most obvious answer is that you did not get the full image file from memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carved files are almost always going to be at least partially incomplete or corrupted. The purpose of carving is to give you a place to start for manual analysis. You should not expect it to fully retrieve all the files in such a complete form that they can be viewed properly in an image viewer.